# Bootstrap navbar not working on iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have a navbar on a page I am building. It works properly on Windows(Chrome/Firefox/IE), Mac OS(Chrome/Firefox/Safari) and on Android(Chrome/Firefox). However, for some reason nothing happens when I click on the File menu from an iPad(Safari or Chrome) nothing happens. I made a stripped down version of the site on jsfiddle and I am having the same issue.

Any ideas?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thraxst/LHWCb/show/)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-brand navbar-right">Not Loaded</div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <div class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">File <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Load</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Restart</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If safari browser not showing Navbar of bootstrap 4: then try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65234112/7186739

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's been reported that leaving off the `href` on your `dropdown-toggle` causes issues with some ios devices.

Change

`<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">File <b class="caret"></b></a>`

to

`<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">File <b class="caret"></b></a>`

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: It happens. From what I can tell, it's only iOS devices that have issues when the href is missing. Strange..

Comment: Thanks that fixed it for me too!  Was only a problem on iOS all other devices seemed to work fine.