# Does Bootstrap 4 work on Safari Browser in Windows?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have created a website, which is working right on all the browsers on Windows but in Safari the layout is quite unstructured. What is the issue? Is the safari on the Windows does not support Bootstrap 4?

Comment: please go through the browser support for bootstrap4 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/browsers-devices/. do check what safari version you are using.

Comment: Apple no longer supports Safari for Windows. Make sure you actually want to support it, because few people use it now.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65234112/7186739

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 4 do not support safari for windows. it only supports safari on mac. you can also go through the browser support for bootstrap 4 here

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/browsers-devices/

[image]

Comment: Actually only few properties are not supported in Safari. But I have fixed all the Safari browser related issues using my custom style. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65234112/7186739

Answer (score 0):

No, Safari Browser version is very old for Windows, it does not support Bootstrap 4. Check your site on Mac Safari latest browser.

Comment: did you try my solution ?, it is working at my side.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed: Bootstrap 4 Issues In Safari Browser**

I have fixed the following issues of bootstrap 4 in Safari browser of windows and all the Browsers used on Mac.

1. Bootstrap 4 Navbar is not showing on Safari.
2. Last Column of a single row is moving to the next row on Safari.

Use this custom style in your own css file

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar-nav{
        margin:0 auto;
        display: -webkit-inline-box;
    }
    .collapse:not(.show) {
        display:block;
    }
    .row{
       display: -webkit-inline-box; 
    }
}
```